Why does LoRA has encoder-decoder structure?
I've learned that LoRA injects trainable rank decomposition 'matrices' into each layer.
A matrix reduces dimension from d to r, and B matrix increases dimension from r to d.
What I'm having trouble in understanding is that why it has this sturucture.
I'm curious what happens if it has simple linear strucutre from dimension d to d.
does the encoder - decoder structure gives some kind of feature learning??

LoRA stands for "low-rank adaptation", use a $d\times d$ matrix, and you get rid of the "LoR" part in the name (aka, that you have full rank)
